# Add cell reference in Google Sheets URL formula for Google Calendar

Tags: google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have a sheet with dates in, I want to add them to Google Calander but cannot get the cell reference in the HYPERLINK to work? Also, will the date format work?

=HYPERLINK("https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text="a7"&dates="b7"&details=&location=")

A7 = Example
B7 = 13-Jan-2022

A7 is formatted as text and B7 as a date.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will allow you to get the link to work. Note though that you'll need to work on the date to create the event on the correct date.

Just add the ampersand (&) character around the cell references to make the concatenation work.

`=HYPERLINK("https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text="&a7&"&dates="&b7&"&details=&location=")`

Comment: Further reading here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73103/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-literal-of-my-cell-to-a-string-of-another-cell